# Connection of WEB API into MVC project for JWT authentication and authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have onr ASP DotNet(6) Core MVC App and now I want to add a web api into to the JWT authentication and authorization.So How will I send the data to the web api for JWT authentication.And after generating the token how will I be able to reuse the token again?

I have studied a lot of articles on JWT addition with WEB API.They are just generating the token by hardcoding.I want to send the login details from the mvc app to the web api and after generating the token I want to reuse it.

Comment: You can use postman . Copy the token that was created. Under "Auth" choose type as "Bearer Token" and paste the copied token key in the "Token" field.

Comment: No my question is user will not use the postman.The token will be stored somewhere in the backend and it will be reused for further requests. So that part can be implemented